# IOS Autolayout MultiLine ULabel issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, multiline

It might be a simple question, but I am a little bit stuck in this. I have a label in my gave the Constraints for `leading top trailing and bottom` to a button. In my case when I remove the bottom constraints the multiline label works properly but when I add buttons constraints then it is not breaking the line. The same thing is working at another place also I am not able to understand what is the issue.

[image]

Comment: You can set height constraint as greater then equal and check. It may solve your issue.

Comment: how can i set the height of the label which's height is going to increase or decrease ?

Comment: You can set height to 0 at start and mark height constraint as >= so if your text assign to label, height will increase based on text height.

Comment: Can you add some screen shots. That way, we can visually see the issue.

Comment: @kokx i tried setting height to 0 but it didn't work me

Comment: @natasha i just added screenshot

Comment: Did you add height constraint with >= ?Can you add screen shot for add constraint?

Comment: its the same i share in the question

Comment: I mean, screen shot for storyboard where constraint show when set.

Comment: Can you take the screen shot of the entire view controller in the Storyboard please, as I can't see any button here.

Comment: You can set the upper and lower limit on the height of label. Upper limit should be according to max number of lines required. Like:-  height >=20  and height <=50 .

Comment: @natasha 1.Daylight is a button only.

Comment: @user3467204 when we are using autolayout it need to be setting it automatically we do not need to set any this type of condition is getting multiple lines.

Comment: But it actually works if we know what number of maximum lines are required . try giving 0 number of lines to label and apply size to fit content to it.

Comment: I have already added 0 to number of line

Answer (score 0):

In able to multiline UILabel, you need to set proper height for the ContentSize.

> If contentSize of UILabel doesn't meet the height then it will not
>   break!

So, for that you need to calculate the height of the UILabelView text. You can do that from the below code:

```
func heightForView(text:String, #font:UIFont, #width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.size.height
}

let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20.0)

var height = heightForView("This is just a load of text", font: font, width: 100.0)
```

After that increase the height of your UILabel according to the text via constraint. For e.g.:

I hope you have already taken the IBOutlet of height constraint of UILabel. So, to update the height, go for below code:

```
_constLabelHeight.constant = label.frame.size.height;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is for objective c and i am not adding any constraint using code.